# ipsec strongswan debian LXC : received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notify error

Tags: debian, ipsec, strongswan

I'm trying to setup a IPSec tunnel between two LXC Debian Jessie on the same physical server (Debian as well). Here is my network topology :

172.17.23.0/24 ---- 172.17.23.100 - VPN1 - 10.73.52.1 ==== 10.73.53.2 - VPN2 - 192.168.100.100 ---- 192.168.100.0/24

The configuration on VPN1 and VPN2 is the same, I'm authenticating with Pre-Shared-Key :

/etc/ipsec.conf
    config setup
      charondebug="all"
      uniqueids=yes

```
conn %default

conn testconn
  left=10.73.53.1
  leftsubnet=172.17.23.0/24
  right=10.73.53.2
  rightsubnet=192.168.100.0/24
  ike=aes128-sha1-modp1024
  esp=aes128-sha1
  keyingtries=0
  ikelifetime=60m
  auto=start
  closeaction=restart
  keylife=20m
  rekeymargin=3m
  keyexchange=ike
  mobike=no
  authby=secret
  type=tunnel
```

/etc/ipsec.secrets
    10.73.53.1 10.73.53.2 : PSK "PasswordHere"

I startup both sides `ipsec start` and up `text` connection `ipsec up`

```
root@vpn1:~# ipsec up testconn
initiating IKE_SA testconn[3] to 10.73.53.2
generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) ]
sending packet: from 10.73.53.1[500] to 10.73.53.2[500] (304 bytes)
received packet: from 10.73.53.2[500] to 10.73.53.1[500] (36 bytes)
parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notify error
establishing connection 'testconn' failed
Idem pour vpn2.
```

I got similar messages in syslog.

I don't understand why I get this `NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN`, as I'm trying to force the choice of algorithms to be used in the `/etc/ipsec.conf` file !

Many thanks for your help, don't hesitate to ask for more informations.

EDIT : Here is extract from /var/log/syslog from VPN2 (receiving connection) :

```
vpn2 charon: 07[NET] sending packet: from 10.73.53.2[500] to 10.73.53.1[500] (940 bytes)
vpn2 charon: 09[NET] received packet: from 10.73.53.1[500] to 10.73.53.2[500] (36 bytes)
vpn2 charon: 09[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
vpn2 charon: 09[IKE] received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notify error
vpn2 charon: 10[NET] received packet: from 10.73.53.254[500] to 10.73.53.2[500] (940 bytes)
vpn2 charon: 10[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) ]
vpn2 charon: 10[IKE] no IKE config found for 10.73.53.2...10.73.53.254, sending NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN
```

I got this `no IKE config found`, googling does not help much :/

EDIT2 : Here is the output of `ipsec statusall` :

```
root@vpn1:~# ipsec statusall
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.2.1, Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64, x86_64):
  uptime: 46 minutes, since Dec 15 14:56:02 2017
  malloc: sbrk 2408448, mmap 0, used 310128, free 2098320
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 0
  loaded plugins: charon aes rc2 sha1 sha2 md5 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default stroke updown
Listening IP addresses:
  172.17.23.10
  10.73.53.1
Connections:
    test:  10.73.53.1...10.73.53.2  IKEv1/2
    test:   local:  [10.73.53.1] uses pre-shared key authentication
    test:   remote: [10.73.53.2] uses pre-shared key authentication
    test:   child:  172.17.23.0/24 === 192.168.100.0/24 TUNNEL
Security Associations (0 up, 0 connecting):
  none
root@vpn1:~#
```

I have exactly the same on server VPN2 (except 172.17.23.0/24 is changed for 192.168.100.0/24, which is local subnet on VPN2 side).

Answer (score 1):

It's not matching the connection attempt to a configuration on your strongswan server.

What's the output if you run 'ipsec statusall'? The command may be 'strongswan statusall' - seems to differ per distro, that'll show what configurations you have loaded

Comment: Thanks DanGahan for your help, I edited my question to show to output of ``ipsec statusall``

Comment: I wonder if it's worth trying to specify the protocol rather than letting it negoiate IKEv1 or IKEv2 - at the moment you have keyexchange=ike which accoring to the man page means Since 5.0.0 both protocols are handled by Charon and connections marked with ike will use IKEv2 when initiating, but accept any protocol version when responding. Worth trying to change that to keyexchange=ikev2 on each end